# Unable to instantiate fragment Android

Tags: android, instantiation

I run my app and I get crash as below.

I don't know what happens.

Unable to instantiate fragment pl.wm.coreguide.fragments.FragmentCalendar: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

It is first time when I crashed app.

Can You look on my code?

```
public class FragmentCalendar extends ListFragment {

    ArrayList<String []> events;
    ArrayAdapter<String []> adapter;

    private Class<?> classToStartOnCLick;
    private int listView = -1;


    public FragmentCalendar(Class<?> classToStartOnCLick,int listView) {
        this.classToStartOnCLick = classToStartOnCLick;
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DatabaseControlReadOnly db = new DatabaseControlReadOnly(getActivity());
        events=db.getAllEvents();

        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(),events);

        setListAdapter(adapter);                
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(listView != -1) return inflater.inflate(listView, container, false);

            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }
```

Comment: Don't know if it helps but...
From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html "All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor."

Comment: tnx. I don't know about this.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah...I believe someone else already put it in comments, but literally only this is missing:

`public FragmentCalendar() {}`